# How to show name of a person with the biggest combined sum in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large data range with buyers and how much they have spent in this company. I need to find the top 3 clients who have spent the most in a year. colon A is the date of purchase colon B is the person and colon C is how much he has spent that day. I need to find the top 3 buyers + how much they have spent their money.

I have tried SUMIF INDEX

The formulas I trie only show the biggest one-time purchase which I dont need I need the total sum.

Comment: Probably something with `LARGE` but since you show/share no (sample)data it's hard to tell what exactly.

Comment: Even a pivot table is most likely an option.

Comment: @JvdV Thank you. I did it with pivot tables then I snip it to top 10 so it doesn't show 200 buyers

Answer (score 0):

The below solution assumes your data is formatted as a table, to make the formulas easier to read.

You'll need a column with a formula like the below:

```
=SUMIFS([Column3],[Column2],<Person>,[Column1],<Date>)
```

Then a column can be added beside Column 4, with a formula like:

```
=IF([@Column4]=LARGE([Column4],1),[@Column2],"")
```

This will return the customer's name if they are the biggest spender for the date specified.